# Sum of weekdays, calculate filtered data

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

This formula

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(Usages!$AB$2:$AB$2029,2)=A2))
```

is used to calculate the number of days that appeared in a list.

Is there a way to only calculate the filtered data?
Looking for something similar to a subtotal function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you're after:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(Usages!$AB$2:$AB$2029,2)=A2)*SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(Usages!$AB$2:$AB$2029,ROW(Usages!$AB$2:$AB$2029)-MIN(ROW(Usages!$AB$2:$AB$2029)),,1)))
```

Plenty of examples on the internet.